# Tempfile stops existing in instance variable outside of block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I have this method that is meant to copy a file from active storage to a tempfile stored on an instance variable

```
def initialize(activity)
    ActiveStorage::Downloader
        .new(activity.original_activity_log_file)
        .download_blob_to_tempfile do |tempfile|
            @activity_file_temp = tempfile
            ap @activity_file_temp.path
        end

    ap @activity_file_temp.path
end
```

When I run this code I see the output

```
"/tmp/ActiveStorage-32-20190316-23089-fdwpa5.fit"
nil
```

Why does the file stop existing on the second print? It feels like a scope issue but I don't think instance variables should be affected like this.

Comment: Scope issue does not quite make sense. Could it be that `#download_blob_to_tempfile` is asynchronous?

Comment: I would argue that is the tempfile is closed at the end of the block (and that is what the docs say) then it makes perfect sense that the `path` of that already closed tempfile returns `nil`.

Comment: I guess you could use `#download_blob_to(file)` instead then if you want a less temporary file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using the `download_blob_to` method instead which saves to a tempfile you provide rather than returning one.

Answer (score 0):

```
def initialize(activity)
  @activity_file_temp = Tempfile.new
  begin 
    ActiveStorage::Downloader
      .new(activity.original_activity_log_file)
      .download_blob_to(@activity_file_temp)
  ensure
    @activity_file_temp.close
  end
end
```

`Tempfile#close` does not unlink the file until the object is finalized.